# Three.js WebGL GPGU Birds Example modify shape & number of vertices

Tags: three.js

I've been tasked with re-purposing the core of this Three.js example for a project demo. http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds The problem is that I've also been asked to change the elements from birds formed of 3 triangles to a different shape. To form the new shape I'll need 3-4x that many triangles/vertices.

Because of the nature of how the example is set up and the fact that the number of birds and their vertices are being created, organized and animated through the buffer geometry and shaders, doing this is difficult (at least for me so far). I've gone through the demo, Tried changing everything I can to change the looping point to what the shader sees as a single bird.

Does anyone smarter than me have any insight (or experience) tweaking this demo to modify the shapes? I have successfully updated the triangles and vertices to what the new shape should be by adding more triangles/vertices to the shape I need.

EXAMPLE: (adding 3 more of these to form the new triangles. )

```
verts_push(
    2, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0
);
verts_push(
    -2, 0, 0,
    -1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0
);
verts_push(
    0, 0, -15,
    20, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0
);
```

EXAMPLE: Doubling the number of triangles/vertices.

```
var triangles = BIRDS * 6;
var points = triangles * 3;
var vertices = new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( points * 3 ), 3 );
```

But somewhere in the code I'm not able to find what I need to modify/multiply so that the shader correctly counts the vertices and knows that the birds are no longer 3 triangles with 9 vertices but now 6 triangles with 18 vertices (or more). I either get errors or or odd shapes with vertices I don't want moving, moving because whatever I've added isn't of the right size of vertices to what the shader is looking for. So far I have had no luck in being able to get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, but that example has been [modified](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html) in the r.78dev branch. Consider using the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I figured out what I needed to modify to both add more triangles and edit what the example considered a single bird. For my purposes I tripled the amount of triangles per "bird" by making the following changes.

Edit 1: Multiplied the number of triangles by an additional 3

```
var triangles = BIRDS * 3 * 3;
```

Edit 2: Increase the number of vertices sets pushed from 3 to 9

```
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
verts_push(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

Edit 3: In the for loop make the following change to the birdVertex attribute

```
birdVertex.array[ v         ] = v % (9 * 3);
```

This successfully gave me enough vertices to play with in order to start creating new shapes as well as controlling the points I wanted to within the birdVS shader.

This worked even with older versions of Three.js (I tested with r.76)